# as3.0 flash: how do i append a string to a variable so flash reads it as a variable?

Tags: flash, variables

i'm getting a value from a class that gives me e.g "icon1" as data.
i want to use this within a function to control the visibility of an item nested in a movieclip on the stage. the nested movie has the same name as the data being sent.

// here's what i want it to do:
mymenu.icon1.visible = true;

// but i cant append the 2 together as flash will see it as a string not read it as path.
e.g
function (iconreceived){

mymenu.iconreceived.viaible = true;
}
any clues?

Answer (score 2):

Use brackets. Since `thing1.thing2` is the same as `thing1["thing2"]`:

```
function setIconVisible(iconReceived:String): void {    
    mymenu[iconReceived].visible = true;
}
```

It's usually not a good idea to have string/name-based references, but the above works.